# Bootstrapping some statistics with non-normal data

Tags: r, bootstrap

I am new to bootstrapping. Assume I have some non-normal data, can be any distribution, it doesn't matter, and I want to find a confidence interval for the mean, median and standard deviation. For the median this question is relevant also for the normal case.
What I don't know is (and asking you to help with) is:

I understand the idea of bootstrapping, the re-sampling idea of generating n samples with replacement, and therefore getting n means, medians or standard deviations. What I don't understand, is how the confidence interval is being calculated. I mean, given a sample of n medians, which aren't normally distributed, how do I calculate it, I don't have Z's or t's values.

Comment: If you have n boostrap estimates of, e.g. the median, then the 0.025 and 0.975 empirical quantiles provide a 95% confidence interval.

Comment: by empirical quantiles do you mean that I take the n medians, i.e. n numbers, and calculate their 0.025 and 0.975 quantiles ?

Comment: yep (more characters)